# .htaccess file not working properly in the sever

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm developing a web site using Codeigniter 3.X. my issue is that it works fine in localhost. now i uploaded the same to my server but it shows some error like "The page you requested was not found."
my `htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fold1/mainfold/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon.ico|images|smileys|js|assets|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fold1/mainfold/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

what is issue with this code ? please help me...

Comment: Did you change your config file according to the server?

Comment: Since you do not have any .htaccess to edit you url you must add an index.php when calling a controller 

and in your config file where there is $config['index_page'] = '' if it is blank add an index.php to it
Check to see it works

Comment: I often ended up naming my htaccess file `.htacces`, with one s. That is one annoying bug to find.

Answer (score 0):

Check the flowing:

Does the paths exist on your server?

Is mod_rewrite enabled on your Apache?

Answer (score 0):

This code for hiding the index.php file .

And  for Controller and method better to use route.php file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason behind the issue. am using codeigniter3.X .Its file naming rules says that controller and model name should be starts with capital letter. i renamed my controller and model files. now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```